# Destination encoding for ros image to opencv image conversion

Tags: ros, opencv, sensor-msgs, depth-image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create an OpenCV image from a ros image using [this](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) . I am subscribing to a topic `/camera/depth/img_rect_color` which is of the type `sensor_msgs/Image` with `32FC1` encoding. How do I specify destination encoding in the following line:

```
cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::32FC1);
```

If I specify `32FC1`, it gives the error :

```
error: invalid suffix "FC1" on integer constant
       cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::32FC1);
                                                                       ^
/home/ubuntu/tst_ws/src/roscv_conv/src/roscv_conv_node.cpp: In member function 'void ImageConverter::imageCb(const ImageConstPtr&)':
/home/ubuntu/tst_ws/src/roscv_conv/src/roscv_conv_node.cpp:39:71: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
```

How can I rectify this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241511/destination-encoding-for-ros-image-to-opencv-image-conversion/) by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2016-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rectified the issue by changing the line as:

```
cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_32FC1);
```

---

Originally posted by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) with karma: 178 on 2016-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0